# access coordinates in circle range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a way to circle through all coordinates that form a circle around the given coordinate.
For example (look the image), if I give the coord of the gray tile and the radius of 9, I need to get all the red tiles coords.

[image: Circle radius 9]

It would be something like a Bresenham's circle algorithm, but I really haven't understood it.

In my case, I´ll use that to erase a circular hole in a tileset.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you map each tile to x,y(Bitmap) then you could iterate through them and see if they are inside the given Circle(Center, Radius)...

Comment: One naive way would be to loop throught the squared bounding box and check if the distance from the point to the center is below your radius. If not, do nothing.

Comment: You could use the circle forumula: https://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/circle/equation-of-a-circle.php Then iterate through the pixels and plug in the coordinates. If the answer is less than the radius squared, the pixel is in the circle. This avoids the sqrt() commonly found in distance calculations. sqrt() is an expensive operation (relatively speaking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for-loop though all the tiles OR recursively

For:

```
public List<Tile> Circle (Tile center, float radius)
{
    List<Tile> inside = new List<Tile>();
    foreach (Tile[] tilerow in Tilemap)
        foreach (Tile tile in tilerow)
            if (Vector2.Distance(center.position, tile.position) <= radius) inside.Add(tile);
    return inside;
}
```

You can also try to use recursion (from the center to all the neighbours while you are inside the circle) - it will be much faster on small maps

Comment: When using a loop you could also consider checking only the tiles that are within radius. So  (center.position.X - radius) to (center.position.X + radius). Useful when you need to limit the amount of tiles checked for performance.